# Latex acronym \acl(*) hanging compilation with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, compiling, acronyms, classicthesis

While writing a Latex document using the acronym package for my glossary I encountered some problems with the `\acl` & `\acl*` commands (also `\acf`) & compilation. On a clean tree without any *.aux* files or anything else than the tex files *pdflatex* gets stuck. With just using `\ac` everything works fine. If I first compile with `\ac` and then switch `\ac` to `\acl` it works, but after removing the compilation files it is stuck again.

I'm using the acronym environment and `classicthesis` with some special config of my university. For compilation I use `arara` with:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
```

```latex
% Insert your acronyms here
\begin{acronym}[CD]
  \acro{cd}[CD]{Continuous Delivery / Continuous Deployment}
  \acro{srp}[SRP]{Single Responsibility Principle}
\end{acronym}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Can you give a full example?  Adding the necessary `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`s etc unsurprisingly doesn't give any issue.  Please provide a full compilable tex document that reproduces your issue.